# WPF Custom attached property that can be empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I need to create a custom attached property that will be able to be empty as shown below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <l:SimpleAttach.MyProperty></l:SimpleAttach.MyProperty>

</Grid>
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
public static class SimpleAttach
{
    public static object GetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty", typeof(object), typeof(SimpleAttach), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

But that just gives an error:

> The property "MyProperty" cannot be empty.

By contrast, MS doesn't seem to have any problem creating empty attached properties. Here is an example that does not give an error about being empty:

```
    <TextBlock Name="VatAmount" Text="hello world" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,111" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
```

So what do I have to do to tell XAML that this property is allowed to be empty?

Comment: do you mean `<l:SimpleAttach.MyProperty>null</l:SimpleAttach.MyProperty>`

Comment: I mean that there should be nothing between the beginning and ending tags. I would expect the actual value therefore to be null.

Reviewing the example of Interaction.Behaviours, I think it is a collection and therefore allows there to be 0 or n items.

Comment: Try set property to <x:Null/>

Comment: So with a little more digging, it would seem that i:Interaction.Behaviors is in fact a BehaviorCollection. So it can have 0 items in its list and therefore will be allowed to be empty in the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I finally figured out my issues. Sometimes it helps to read the official documentation: [XAML Syntax In Detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723(v=vs.100).aspx)

In particular I seemed to be referring to "Content properties".

> XAML content syntax is a syntax that is only enabled on classes that specify the ContentPropertyAttribute as part of their class declaration. The ContentPropertyAttribute references the property name that is the content property for that type of element (including derived classes). When processed by a XAML processor, any child elements or inner text that are found between the opening and closing tags of the object element will be assigned to be the value of the XAML content property for that object.

Second of all, in the example of Microsofts Interactivity.Behaviors, that is a collection and collections are allowed to have 0 items in them.

Furthermore, if you go down the road of implementing an attached behavior that is a collection, then this post will guide you through the quirks: [Attached property of type list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448899/attached-property-of-type-list)