# Attached property of type list but without an encolsed tag

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448969), but when I comment out the container

```
            <tly:MyDataGridHelper.HiddenCols> 
                <!--  <tly:LabelCollection>  -->
                    <Label Name="SomeProp"/>
                    <Label Name="DisplayName"/>
                <!--</tly:LabelCollection>  -->
            </tly:MyDataGridHelper.HiddenCols>
```

and I change only the name of the string passed to `RegisterAttached`

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HiddenColsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HiddenColsInternal", typeof(LabelCollection), typeof(MyDataGridHelper), new PropertyMetadata
        {
            PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
            {
                var grid = (DataGrid)obj;
                if (grid != null) {
                    var arr = ((LabelCollection)e.NewValue).Cast<Label>().ToArray();
                    hidden[grid.Name] = (arr ?? new Label[0]).Select(l => l.Name).ToArray();
               }
            }
        });
```

but if I have to initialize the collection in the getter

```
    public static LabelCollection GetHiddenCols(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        var collection = (LabelCollection)obj.GetValue(HiddenColsProperty);
        if (collection == null) {
            collection = new LabelCollection();
            obj.SetValue(HiddenColsProperty, collection);
        }
        return collection;
    }
```

then my values (my label names: `"SomeProp`" and `"DisplayName"` for example) are lost. What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to get them?

At the moment my workaround is to keep the envelop `<tly:LabelCollection>` (and everything works in this case)

Comment: what's the problem with leaving it inside a `LabelCollection`?

Comment: [last (deleted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41970983/1506454) suggests "Your attached property should not have a SetXxx method - just remove it". do it make any difference if you remove "Set" method?

Comment: You are not supposed to change the name that the property is registered with. If you want to access it in XAML as `HiddenCols`, you'll have to register it with that name and also provide the static getter and setter methods `GetHiddenCols`and `SetHiddenCols`. Everything else is a hack, creating more trouble than necessary.

Comment: Well, your code actually works for me without a Set method and "HiddenColsInternal" as property name, but I would not recommend to implement it that way. A Binding on the attached property would not work. It is a hack, only for saving a single XAML tag.

Comment: How did you declare the `PropertyMetadata`? Your code seems to be incompleted

Comment: The PropertyChangedCallback is only called once, when the property value is initially set. Later there are only elements added to the collection, but that does not change the value of the HiddenCols property.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference between the two versions of your XAML.

While

```
<tly:MyDataGridHelper.HiddenCols> 
    <tly:LabelCollection>
        <Label Name="SomeProp"/>
        <Label Name="DisplayName"/>
    </tly:LabelCollection>
</tly:MyDataGridHelper.HiddenCols>
```

creates and populates a new collection object before assigning it to the `HiddenCols` property,

```
<tly:MyDataGridHelper.HiddenCols> 
    <Label Name="SomeProp"/>
    <Label Name="DisplayName"/>
</tly:MyDataGridHelper.HiddenCols>
```

just populates an already created collection instance that had been assigned to the property before being populated.

However, your PropertyChanged callback expects an already populated collection, so you have to use the first variant.

For the second variant, the collection type could probably implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, and you could attach a `CollectionChanged` event handler. Or you access the property later, e.g. in a Loaded event handler.

Comment: No idea what the XAML parser is exactly doing there. IMO there is not much sense in trying to avoid creating a new collection instance in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid to create the `LabelCollection` in your XAML or in your getter, you need to use a generic `ObservableCollection` as the property type of the `HiddenCols` property.
Then with "some" reflection:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HiddenColsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HiddenColsInternal", typeof(ObservableCollection<Label>), typeof(MyDataGridHelper), new PropertyMetadata
    {
        DefaultValue = GetObservableCollectionDefaultValueFactory(),
        PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
        {
            var grid = (DataGrid)obj;
            if (grid != null)
            {
                var arr = ((LabelCollection)e.NewValue).Cast<Label>().ToArray();
                hidden[grid.Name] = (arr ?? new Label[0]).Select(l => l.Name).ToArray();
            }
        }

private static object GetObservableCollectionDefaultValueFactory()
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("MS.Internal.ObservableCollectionDefaultValueFactory`1, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
    Type closedType = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(Label));
    ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = closedType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    return constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You never end up learning! You are right @Clemens, my answer is not correct

Comment: @Clemens, I fixed my answer with some reflection

Comment: My point still stands, all this only to avoid creating a collection instance in XAML? I don't like it, sorry.

Comment: I agree with you @Clemens, it's not worth the hassle. But maybe user1892538 needs it for some reason.